# How do I enable/disable an LDAP user?

Tags: java, ldap

I'm using the following java code to authenticate an LDAP user. This will succeed if the object exists with the specified username and password. However, I don't see any properties on the user which would allow me to activate/deactivate the user. Specifically, I just want to set a property on the user which would make authentication fail without actually deleting the entire object.

Can this be done directly or do I need to write separate code which loads the user and checks that a field is marked active or inactive?

```
public static boolean authenticate(String url, String securityAuthentication, String securityPrincipal, String usernameKey, String username, String password) {
    try {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        env.put(InitialContext.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, securityAuthentication);
        env.put(InitialContext.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, usernameKey +"="+ username + securityPrincipal);
        env.put(InitialContext.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password );
        // Create the initial context
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        return true;
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm told that in we have one that's active directory and another which is 389 Directory Server.

Comment: What schema are you using for users? Also, you must close that context, in a 'finally' block.

Comment: I would use a specific group for the purpose. The users belonging to that group don't have enough permissions for logging in...